# Is there a way to distinguish out the IntermediateSystem-related HTTP request and response headers?

Tags: http, http-headers

In the wikipedia [HTTP header fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Common_non-standard_request_fields):

There list many HTTP header fields, but I did not found a way to distinguish the headers about intermediate system(Such as CDN/HTTP Proxy).

Is there a way to distinguish out the IntermediateSystem-related HTTP header fields? or is there any link introduce it?

Answer (score 0):

All the HTTP headers can send to proxy, there can only distinguished by whether Proxy modify the headers: `End-to-end headers` and `Hop-by-hop headers`.

**End-to-end headers**
These headers must be transmitted to the final recipient of the message: the server for a request, or the client for a response. Intermediate proxies must retransmit these headers unmodified and caches must store them.

**Hop-by-hop headers**
These headers are meaningful only for a single transport-level connection, and must not be retransmitted by proxies or cached. Note that only hop-by-hop headers may be set using the Connection general header.

and if you want to find more proxy-related,

from [developer.mozilla.org - HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers):

> Headers can also be grouped according to how **proxies** handle them:
> Connection
> Keep-Alive
> Proxy-Authenticate
> Proxy-Authorization
> TE
> Trailer
> Transfer-Encoding
> Upgrade (see also Protocol upgrade mechanism).